# LightDM cannot start - VMWare can't launch Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, boot, lightdm, vmware

I tried booting to my ubuntu after a reboot, and I got an error.
I am prompted with this screen:

[image: First Screen]

Afterwards, I get these options:

[image: The options]

But, no matter what I choose, I end up eventually getting this screen mentioning

```
Failed to start Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up
```

and stopping LightDM,

[image: Error screen]

I tried booting with TTY but that didn't work.

I searched StackExchange, and no question mentioned getting stuck here, but on later screens where terminal access is already achieved.
Thanks!

EDIT: I have ended up "giving up" on this VM. No solution worked. I managed to boot to TTY eventually, and I extracted the files I actually need using SCP.